# Invalid Request Issue After Successful Form Submission: Compressed Image and Text Storage

Tags: javascript, php, html, post, compression

I'm currently facing an issue in a form containing two inputs—one for image upload and another for text entry. Upon clicking the upload button, both the compressed image and text are successfully stored in the database, with the image correctly saved in the designated folder. However, upon navigating to the subsequent page, an 'Invalid Request' message appears, pinpointing an issue with the IF condition in the PHP code related to the POST method.

I attempted to address the issue by modifying the upload button type to 'submit.' However, this resulted in a shift in the code's behavior. Now, the original image before compression is stored in a distinct row in the database, yet it not stored in the images folder. Simultaneously, the compressed image, along with the entered text, is stored in a separate row, with the compressed image correctly saved in the designated folder.

(Note that I'm using two libraries one is compressorjs and the other is axios)

This is my HTML, JS, and PHP code....

```
<body>
<form action="direct.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="mainimg">
        <input type="file" id="file" accept="image/*" name="file" onchange="compressImg()">
    </div>
    <div class="test">
        <input type="text" name="test">
    </div>
    <button type="button" onclick="uploadData()">Upload</button>
</form>

<script src="compressorjs-main/dist/compressor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/1.6.3/axios.min.js"></script>
<script>
    let formData;

    function compressImg() {
        const fileInput = document.getElementById('file');
        const file = fileInput.files[0];

        if (!file) {
            return;
        }

        new Compressor(file, {
            quality: 0.6,
            maxWidth: 700,
            maxHeight: 700,
            success(result) {
                formData = new FormData();
                console.log('Original Size:', file.size);
                console.log('Compressed Size:', result.size);
                console.log("Image name after compression", result.name);

                // Append the compressed image
                formData.delete('file');
                formData.append('file', result, result.name);
            },
            error(err) {
                console.log(err.message);
            },
        });
    }

    function uploadData() {
        // Check if formData is defined
        if (formData) {
            // Append the test value to the formData
            formData.append('test', document.querySelector('[name="test"]').value);

            axios.post('direct.php', formData).then(() => {
                console.log('Upload success');
                window.location.href = 'direct.php';
                console.log(formData);
            });
        } else {
            console.log('No data to upload');
        }
    }
</script>
```

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
$compressedImage = $_FILES['file'];
$test = $_POST['test'];

echo "Original File Name: " . $compressedImage['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Original File Size: " . $compressedImage['size'] . "<br>";

$targetDir = 'accountimage/';
$targetFile = $targetDir . basename($compressedImage['name']);

move_uploaded_file($compressedImage['tmp_name'], $targetFile);

echo "Moved File Name: " . $compressedImage['name'] . "<br>";
echo "Moved File Size: " . filesize($targetFile) . "<br>";

$sql = "INSERT INTO gameaccount (pic, test) VALUES (?, ?)";

$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

$stmt->bind_param("ss", $targetFile, $test);

$stmt->execute();

$stmt->close();

$conn->close();

echo 'Upload good';} else {echo 'Invalid request';}
```

Comment: `window.location.href = 'direct.php';`?  This is sending you to direct.php and the request method will be GET, so you see "invalid request".   Perhaps this should load a different url or simply not be here?

Comment: This line sends me to direct.php because without this line, when I click upload, all the stuff, image and text will be stored, but I will still be on the same page,i want when click upload to sends me to another page for other purposes for now(direct.php).

Comment: Well then you need to have something else in direct.php which actually shows you some useful content, rather than just displaying "Invalid request" when it doesn't receive a POST request. It only displays "Invalid request" because that's exactly what you told it to do (with the `else {echo 'Invalid request';}` code). It's not a bug. And it's unclear what you're expecting to happen instead?

Comment: `I attempted to address the issue by modifying the upload button type to 'submit.' `...that would cause the form to be submitted directly, and the JS code which does the compression would be ignored (or if you're lucky, it'll be uploaded separately if there's time for the Axios request to still run before the page is removed from the browser, which it sounds like might be happening), which presumably isn't helpful for you.

Comment: `both the compressed image and text are successfully stored in the database`.... from looking at the code I assume you actually meant `both the path to the compressed image and the text are successfully stored in the database` ?

Comment: `stored in a separate column`... I assume you mean `row` not `column`? `INSERT` commands create new rows in the database. Please try to take care with descriptions and terminology, otherwise it can create unnecessary ambiguity, which can then obscure your problem for those reading about it.

Comment: It's a row sorry. Currently, I'm seeking a solution to ensure the form is submitted using the POST method, even without relying on Axios. However, changing the upload button type to 'submit' results in two posts: one for the original form and another for Axios. I'm looking for a way to post only the original form with compressed images, either without using Axios or by ensuring Axios utilizes a POST request. Placing the compressed image in a separate input and retrieving it with PHP is a potential last resort. Any insights or solutions to address these concerns are greatly appreciated.

Comment: `ensuring Axios utilizes a POST request`...it is already doing that (otherwise it wouldn't be saving your data successfully). As we already told you, its the subsequent `window.location.href` command which sends a GET request.

Comment: `even without relying on Axios`...that might be possible but not very efficient- you'd need to get the compressed image data from JS, encode it to a base64 string put it in a hidden field in the form before the form is submitted, and then have php decode it again before it saves it. This will be slower and also increase the size of the payload (because base64 encoded represents the data using more space than binary)

Comment: Surely all you need to do, as we mentioned before, is change `window.location.href = "direct.php"` to `window.location.href = "someOtherPage.php"` - i.e. a page which shows whatever information you are wanting to display when the upload is complete. Again, as we alsp mentioned before you haven't explained what you actually want to show to the user in that situation.

Comment: Thank you, ADyson, for your valuable support and insights. I've come to understand that changing the button type to `'submit'` is not advisable. If set to 'submit,' it triggers the original form submission, resulting in two posts. Therefore, the recommended approach is to keep the button type as `'button'` and handle the form submission entirely through JavaScript. This allows for better control over the process and prevents unintended multiple submissions. am i right?

Comment: It mainly ensures that you can use the compressed image variable and send it to the direct.php script easily. If you weren't doing that particular task, then you could have chosen between axios or a traditional submit. But the compression makes axios a better choice in this case because you can more easily include the compressed image data in the requedt.

Comment: Thanks you ADyson, for your help appreciate that